# ServiceStack New API - How to get raw request/response

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm using the new `ServiceStack.Client` to consume a ServiceStack API, and to make a simple prototype to a client, as they are using PHP, I would like to show the raw request and response that internally ServiceStack is using to make the request.

**Is there anything I can hook up in the client side to get the raw URL and data that is been sent to the API** as well the raw json that we're getting from the API call?

I'm simply using, as an example:

```
var service = new JsonServiceClient(gko_url);
var response = service.Post<Authenticate>("/auth", new Authenticate()
{
    UserName = username,
    Password = password,
    RememberMe = true
});
```

Comment: Do you want it for development/debugging purposes, or as part of the application?

Comment: @RaulNoheaGoodness just so I can output in the page. The project would be just for show off, so  the clients can use their own language if not using `C#`. For a direct answer to your question: as part of the application.

Comment: You can use any REST client you want, you don't need ServiceStack's own client. You could even create a raw HTTP request and execute a GET, or use `curl` to do the same. That would be a better way to show that ServiceStack (or ASP.NET Web API) only use HTTP requests and Json

Comment: You can just use Fiddler to capture the raw Request/Response. Also the [Request Logger plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) might be useful to see what requests are processed by ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to inspect the raw HTTP request & response between the ServiceStack Client and service, the easiest way is to run the [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) proxy on the same PC as the client.

Then set the ServiceStack client to use fidder as a proxy (running on localhost port 8888 by default):

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(gko_url);
IWebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8888");
client.Proxy = webProxy;
var response = client.Post<Authenticate>("/auth", new Authenticate()
{
    UserName = username,
    Password = password,
    RememberMe = true
});
```

You can then inspect the raw HTTP Request and Response between the client and the server via the Fiddler UI. That will give you and others confidence the "over the wire" communication is pure HTTP+JSON , and language-independent.

This may be more effective to "show off", since you are not asking the ServiceStack client to give you the raw HTTP communication - it is coming from a completely different application (Fiddler web proxy).

Comment: The idea as I said in the question comment, was to append to the application, [just like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oYo5F.png) - So the client can followup what's going on for each step and easily convert to it's own language, or simply using *RestSharp* as manual calls, for example...

Comment: If you want, you can use any web client with the servicestack service. You don't have to use the SS client. Try using a browser-based utility to dump the request and response, such as Advanced REST Client for chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US

Comment: I think you're missing my point completely, maybe it's me that did not do a good job explaining it better...